# How to print maximum minimum and average value from the input numbers in Python?

Tags: python, max, min

Program will ask the input from the user:
inp = input("Enter numbers")

User might input number as 4535435439. My first question is how do I store the number as list. For example if the user input as 12, 14, 15. I want each numbers to be stored as a list. Is there any inbuild function? And how do I get maximum, minimum and average value from that list?

P.S I dont need the code. Please guide me in the logic. Tell me how can I do it? Then I will transform that into code and put in here. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

If the numbers are comma separated, you are in luck

```
import ast
numbers = ast.literal_eval(inp)
```

will give you a tuple of the numbers. Converting a tuple to a list is easy

```
numbers = list(numbers)
```

There are functions `min()` and `max()` you can use to find the min and max, just pass `numbers` to them

You can do `min` (or `max`) without the builtin functions like this

```
min_number = numbers[0]
for n in numbers:
    if n < min_number:
        min_number = n
```

`max` is similar

To get the average, add the numbers and divide by the length

```
total = 0
for n in numbers:
    total += n
average = float(total)/len(numbers)
```

in Python2 you need to convert one of the numbers to `float`, otherwise you will get an integer divison. Hopefully you are using Python3 as I see you are using `input()` instead of `raw_input()`

The shortcut ways is to use the `sum()` function

```
average = sum(numbers)/len(numbers)
```

Comment: Thank you gnibbler for you help. But how can I do it without using the Python functions. I want to get logically strong. How can I do it using loop?

Comment: @sachitad, I added it to my answer

Comment: Thank you so much for you help. Appreciate it :)

Comment: can u please explain what you did there? what is builtin functions? How does it code work?

Comment: @sachitad, builtin functions are like `min()`, `max()`, `sum()` etc.

Comment: Yes I am using Python 3.2.3. Thank you so much for you help! I understand it now! THnx

Answer (score 1):

```
min(int(x) for x in raw_input().split(','))
```

Will get an input from the user. If the string is comma seperated numbers, eg `1, 2, 3, 4`, this will split the string into each number, convert them to integers, find the minimum of that list of values.

Comment: You don't' need the `[]`. `min()` works fine with a generator expression

Answer (score 0):

You could ask the user for a number in a loop, and accept empty input as end if input and break out of the loop. In the loop you just append the input to a list.